# What is scope of register storage class?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to know what is exactly the difference between everystorage  classes. Here I have used register Storage class. So I am confuse that if we declare register variable as global what is the scope of it? 
    In my code it is giving that the register name not specified for ‘x’ .Please guide me if anyone one knows what exactly it is saying and what is the scope of register varibale compared to other storage class?
    Thank you.!!!

```
 below is the output of terminal using gcc compiler in Ubuntu.

 shilpi@shilpi:~/storageclass$ gcc register.c
 register.c:9:15: error: register name not specified for ‘x’
 register int x=10;
           ^
 shilpi@shilpi:~/storageclass$ gcc register.c
 register.c:9:15: error: register name not specified for ‘x’
 register int x=10;
           ^



//int x = 10 ;
int z;
int main( )
{
   extern int y ;
  // register int x ;
   printf ( "The value of x is %d \n", x ) ;
   printf ( "The value of y is %d",y ) ;
   z=add();
   printf("\nvalue of sum is : %d", z);
   return 0;

}
int y = 200 ;

int add()
{
    int sum;
    sum=x+y;
    //printf("value of sum is : %d", sum);
}
```

Comment: is this error belongs to posted code?

Comment: forgett simply `register`keyword at all. Is there any compiler which do not ignore that keyword? As I remember the last valid code I saw was in the early eighties. ;)

Comment: "The scope of register variables is local to the block in which they are declared. "

Comment: @Klaus, it is not used often, true, but it should be used more. It specifies that the address of the variable shouldn't be taken, so it can be a usefull optimization hint. In particular `register` variables that are also `const` qualified can never alias.

Comment: I disagree! The compiler is able to generate a complete data and execution tree and knows exactly which values will be const or not const, also if they are never declared const. And which value should stay in a register can only be answered by a deep analysis of the optimized! code. Believe us: The compiler knows much more about the machine implementation as the programmer :-)

Comment: @Klaus: in contrast to `restrict`, the use-case for `register` is not so much to provide a hint for the compiler, but to prevent the programmer from doing things he shouldn't do; the same is true for pointer-to-`const`: it has absolutely no benefit for optimization purposes as casting it away is perfectly fine, but it makes the programmer jump through additional hoops when doing things that might be ill-advised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In standard C `register` is only allowed inside functions, and then such a variable as a visibility scope that goes from its declaration to the end of the block where that declaration occurs.

As such `register` has not much to do with hardware registers of your platform, it is a missnomer. Its purpose is an optimization hint: you are not allowed to take the address of such a variable.

Gcc has an extension that also allows to relate such `register` variables to real hardware registers. That extension can also be used at file scope, and this is the error message that you see.

Comment: I am not getting how to use register variables. Like Why it is giving this error only. I have used register in the function so it works like local . but when we write it global then can it b used or not?

Comment: @ShilpeeDave, as I said generally it can't be used in global scope. gcc allows a special syntax to associate a `register` to a hardware register. This one (with this extension) you can use in global scope, but only if you compile with gcc, other compilers wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See the standard 6.9:

> The storage-class specifiers auto and register shall not appear in the
>   declaration specifiers in an external declaration.

The definition of an "external declaration" is explained as:

> As discussed in 5.1.1.1, the unit of program text after preprocessing
>   is a translation unit, which consists of a sequence of external
>   declarations. These are described as ‘‘external’’ because they appear
>   outside any function (and hence have file scope).

(Not to be confused with the **extern** keyword.)

So your code is not valid, register variables always have local scope.

Please note that the register keyword is pretty much obsolete nowadays: compilers are far better than programmers at deciding when it is suitable to store a variable in a CPU register.